# ios Swift 2.3 - slider with mapview in landscape

Tags: ios, slider, mkmapview, zooming

I have an app that is built with Swift 2.3.

It contains a view with a mapview component.

The view also contains a slider for zooming in and out of the map.

The zooming in and out works fine in portrait orientation, but crashes in landscape with the following error:
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '

The error occurs, in landscape orientation, when I slide the slider too far to the left.

I assume that I need to adjust the code some how based on the orientation.

Any ideas?   Are you aware of any examples that would useful?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue when the value generated by the slider is an invalid for creating a region.  You could log the value of the slider as you're sliding it to the left to the point where it crashes.  Then set the lowest value before it crashes as the minimum value for your slider.  You may want to test the same with the max value.